Why am I receiving a 429 error from the Twitter API (api.x.com/2/users/:userId/tweets) despite being under the monthly cap?
I am using the twitter-api-v2 Node.js module to fetch tweets for a specific user with the endpoint api.x.com/2/users/:userId/tweets. However, I am encountering the following error:
ApiResponseError: Request failed with code 429
    at RequestHandlerHelper.createResponseError (/var/task/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/cjs/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:104:16)
    at RequestHandlerHelper.onResponseEndHandler (/var/task/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/cjs/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:262:25)
    at Gunzip.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  error: true,
  type: 'response',
  code: 429,
  headers: {
    date: 'Wed, 11 Dec 2024 20:40:22 UTC',
    perf: '7402827104',
    server: 'tsa_b',
    'set-cookie': [
      'guest_id=v1%3A173394962230192184; Max-Age=34214400; Expires=Sun, 11 Jan 2026 20:40:22 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.x.com; Secure; SameSite=None'
    ],
    'api-version': '2.118',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0',
    'content-length': '197',
    'x-access-level': 'read',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    'x-transaction-id': 'e3955136f420726d',
    'x-xss-protection': '0',
    'x-rate-limit-limit': '40000',
    'x-rate-limit-reset': '1733950522',
    'x-rate-limit-remaining': '39999',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631138519',
    'x-response-time': '15',
    'x-connection-hash': '1ead51a2bf19d6b41fec72fc9c54b52ec589877c834048cb85b76871684aff94'
  },
  rateLimit: { limit: 40000, remaining: 39999, reset: 1733950522 },
  data: {
    account_id: 1866140657460359200,
    product_name: 'standard-basic',
    title: 'UsageCapExceeded',
    period: 'Monthly',
    scope: 'Product',
    detail: 'Usage cap exceeded: Monthly product cap',
    type: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/usage-capped'
  }
}

My observations:

The error mentions a "Monthly product cap exceeded" despite the fact that my dashboard shows:
Monthly Post cap usage: 40 Posts pulled of 100.

My rate limit headers indicate that I have plenty of room left:
x-rate-limit-remaining: 39999 and x-rate-limit-limit: 40000.

This issue seems related to my account-level product cap rather than per-endpoint rate limits.


My setup:

API library: twitter-api-v2
Subscription plan: Free
API endpoint: api.x.com/2/users/:userId/tweets

What I’ve tried:

Verified the dashboard for usage caps.
Checked the rate limit headers from the response.
Ensured my API requests comply with the endpoint's rate limits.

Questions:

Why am I seeing a 429 UsageCapExceeded error when my dashboard shows I haven’t exceeded the monthly cap?
Could this be an issue with the Twitter API's product-specific limitations or configuration on my account?
How can I resolve or debug this issue further?

